# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown collation: 'utf8_0900_ai_ci'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am a newbie trying to learn ruby on rails by following the Lynda video series using ROR version 5.0 and mysql 8.02. after creating my table entries in DB>migrate>model.rb file and running "rails db:migrate" i get an error in the terminal which does not make a lot of sense to. iv using a different user and grating it mysql privileges and searching on the web but no luck.

=============================

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

def up
    create_table :users do |t|

```
    t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
    t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
    t.string "email", :default => '', :null => false
    t.string "password", :limit => 40

  t.timestamps
end
```

end

def down

```
drop_table :users
```

end

## end

MBP:simple_cms $ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown collation: 'utf8_0900_ai_ci': CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_0900_ai_ci PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in`block in query'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in`query'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in `block in execute'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in`block in log'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in`log'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in `execute'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:31:in`execute'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:278:in `create_table'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:423:in`create_table'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:27:in `create_table'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:1008:in`initialize_schema_migrations_table'

Comment: ***which does not make a lot of sense to me. iv used a different mysql user and granting it mysql privileges and searching on the web but no luck.

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `show variables like 'collation_database';`

Comment: thanks for the response ....where would i find that? in mysql or command line terminal?

Comment: Run it in the `mysql client`

Comment: mysql> show variables like 'collation_database';
+--------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name      | Value              |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| collation_database | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+--------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.26 sec)

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue related to your problem : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28730

This has been fixed in `rails v5.1.0.rc2`. Upgrading to the latest version and regenerating `schema.rb` should eliminate your problem.

Comment: my rails version is Rails 5.0.6 and i tried using "bundle update rails" but will not update to 5.1 i have also tried gem 'rails', '~> 5.1' but comes back with an error..... isnt updating rails to new versions suppose to be easy?

Comment: A `bundle update` will only push your `minor version` to the latest. I'd suggest you first change the version in the Gemfile to `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1'`, and then run `bundle update rails`. You won't get errors then.

Comment: thank you that fixed it! i can see my tables now in mysql your man bitsapien.

Comment: @bitsapien Thanks! We were running MySQL 8.x and were trying to upgrade Rails 4.2 to 5.0 and ran into this error. Ended up having to upgrade to Rails 5.2 instead to get this fix in place.

Answer (score 1):

Also it's possible to add general `collation` to your `database.yml` if `utf8_0900_ai_ci` doesn't work:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  ...
  encoding: utf8
  collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who cannot upgrade to rails `v5.1.0.rc2`, and adding `collation` to `database.yml` didn't work, collation should be modified in the database level.

Run the command below in mysql console:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci;
```